# microsoft recommenders DKN running on Azure ML sturdio

Tags: azure, tensorflow, gpu, azure-machine-learning-service

I installed recommenders[gpu] library, and want to run the DKN model on GPU of Azure ML studio. I installed the cudatoolkit=11.2 and cudnn=8.2 according to the provided link https://pypi.org/project/recommenders/ with Conda in my environment. But when i run this below code

```
import os
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
print(f"System version: {sys.version}")
print(f"Tensorflow version: {tf.__version__}")

from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
import logging
# import papermill as pm
# import scrapbook as sb
#tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR') # only show error messages

import recommenders
from recommenders.datasets.download_utils import maybe_download
from recommenders.datasets.mind import (download_mind,
                                        extract_mind,
                                        read_clickhistory,
                                        get_train_input,
                                        get_valid_input,
                                        get_user_history,
                                        get_words_and_entities,
                                        generate_embeddings)
from recommenders.models.deeprec.deeprec_utils import prepare_hparams
from recommenders.models.deeprec.models.dkn import DKN
from recommenders.models.deeprec.io.dkn_iterator import DKNTextIterator
```

i get this warning.

> W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

and also when i run this below code

```
import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

i get this below output

> []

and my code does not run on GPU.

I expect to run the code on GPU.